# ELI5: Explanation of why the product of divisors of a natural $n$ is always $n^{\frac{d(n)}{2}}$ where $d(n)$ gives the number of divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

I tried reading the answers on [Product of Divisors of some $n$ proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126001/product-of-divisors-of-some-n-proof) and unfortunately couldn't understand them. The accepted answer mentions that

${\displaystyle\prod_\limits{d|n}{d^2}=\prod_\limits{d|n}{d\frac{n}{d}} = \prod_\limits{d|n}{n}=n^{d(n)} }$ where $d(n)$ gives the number of divisors of a number $n$ over $\mathbb N$,

which I assume proves something about the product of (every divisor of $n$ squared) being equal to $n^{d(n)}$. But I still don't get how this is related to the conclusion.

Comment: Which part do you find confusing? One of the equalities or just the conclusion?

Comment: The equality between the first two $\prod$s as well as how it connects to the conclusion.

Comment: The main idea is to pair up the divisors. For every divisor $d$ of $n$, the number $n/d$ is also a divisor of $n$.

Comment: The part you seem to be missing is that the product of (every divisor of n, squared) is equal to (the product of every divisor of n), squared.  Taking square roots of both sides gives the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bearer of the curse, first $d$ is a divisor of $n\iff$ $\frac{n}{d}$ is a divisor of $n$. This is because $d\cdot\frac{n}{d}=n$, and $\frac{n}{d}$ is an integer. This would mean that $$\prod_{d\mid n} d=\prod_{d\mid n} \frac{n}{d}\tag{1}$$ because both products run over the same divisors just in opposite order. Multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $\prod_{d\mid n} d$ gives $$\prod_{d\mid n} d^2=\prod_{d\mid n} d\prod_{d\mid n} \frac{n}{d}=\prod_{d\mid n} n\tag{2}$$

For the last equality you get an $n$ for each divisor $d$. There are $d(n)$ divisors, we get

$$\prod_{d\mid n} d^2=n^{d(n)}\tag{3}$$

Now, $\prod_{d\mid n} d^2=\left(\prod_{d\mid n} d\right)^2$ so taking the square-root of both sides of $(3)$ yields $$\prod_{d\mid n} d=n^{\frac{d(n)}{2}}$$

Comment: Haha, did you start your answer with a Dark Souls II reference? ^^

Comment: @DullandWitlessBoi Yes, indeed!

Comment: Absolutely love the reference. I'm about to clear the Dragon Shrine for the first time.

Comment: @DullandWitlessBoi Good luck! Don’t you dare go hollow!

Comment: Lol, why thank you

Answer (score 3):

List the factors in increasing order, then again in decreasing order, then multiply the first number in each list, the second etc. There are $d(n)$ calculations that each return $n$, so the overall product is $n^{d(n)}$. The product of $n$'s factors is just the square root of this, since we listed the factors twice.